# find free variables in lambda expression

Tags: functional-programming, lisp, scheme

Does anyone know how I can figure out the free variables in a lambda expression? Free variables are the variables that aren't part of the lambda parameters.

My current method (which is getting me nowhere) is to simply use car and cdr to go through the expression. My main problem is figuring out if a value is a variable or if it's one of the scheme primitives. Is there a way to test if something evaluates to one of scheme's built-in functions? For example:

```
(is-scheme-primitive? 'and)
;Value: #t
```

I'm using MIT scheme.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### [EDIT 4] Disclaimer; or, looking back a year later:

This is actually a really bad way to go about solving this problem.  It works as a *very* quick and dirty method that accomplishes the basic goal of the OP, but does not stand up to any 'real life' use cases.  Please see the discussion in the comments on this answer as well as the other answer to see why.

#### [/EDIT]

This solution is probably less than ideal, <s>but it will work for any lambda form you want to give it in the REPL environment of mit-scheme</s> (see edits).  Documentation for the procedures I used is found at [the mit.edu doc site.](http://web.mit.edu/scheme_v9.0.1/doc/mit-scheme-ref/Environments.html#Environments)  `get-vars` takes a quoted `lambda` and returns a list of pairs.  The first element of each pair is the symbol and the second is the value returned by `environment-reference-type`.

```
(define (flatten lst)
  (cond ((null? lst) ())
        ((pair? (car lst)) (append (flatten (car lst)) (flatten (cdr lst))))
        (else
          (cons (car lst) (flatten (cdr lst))))))

(define (get-free-vars proc-form)
  (let ((env (ge (eval proc-form user-initial-environment))))
    (let loop ((pf (flatten proc-form))
               (out ()))
      (cond ((null? pf) out)
            ((symbol? (car pf))
             (loop (cdr pf) (cons (cons (car pf) (environment-reference-type env (car pf))) out)))
            (else
              (loop (cdr pf) out))))))
```

EDIT:  Example usage:

```
(define a 100)

(get-vars '(lambda (x) (* x a g)))
 => ((g . unbound) (a . normal) (x . unbound) (* . normal) (x . unbound) (lambda . macro))
```

EDIT 2: Changed code to guard agains calling `environment-reference-type` being called with something other than a symbol.

EDIT 3: As Sam has pointed out in the comments, this will not see the symbols bound in a let under the lambda as having any value.. not sure there is an easy fix for this.  So, my statement about this taking any `lambda` is wrong, and should have read more like "Any simple `lambda` that doesn't contain new binding forms"... oh well.

Comment: This won't work for this program: `(lambda (x) (let ((y 1)) (+ x y)))`.

Comment: @Sam You are correct. It was breaking on calling `environment-reference-type` on integers, but even after guarding against that, it will not see any binding made within the `lambda`.

Comment: @oobivat. One of the stipulations of this HW question is that their will be no let under the lambda so this solution will work fine. Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Will study your solution and try to implement myself.

Comment: This has lots of other problems as well: consider `(lambda () (quote x))`.  `flatten` is just not a good way to process Scheme programs.

Comment: @SamTobin-Hochstadt Yes, this is a very "quick and dirty" solution.  Your point is well taken though that `flatten` is really a poor choice here since it destroys all syntax.  I may revisit this at some point... do you suppose that it would be possible to implement an `expand` macro in mit-scheme?

Comment: @oobivat, you can't implement `expand` without hooking into the macro expander itself.  After all, we don't know what the core MIT Scheme forms even are -- it might implement `let` using `lambda`, or it might have `let` as a primitive.

Answer (score 6):

For arbitrary MIT Scheme programs, there isn't any way to do this.  One problem is that the function you describe just can't work.  For example, this doesn't use the 'scheme primitive' `and`:

```
(let ((and 7)) (+ and 1))
```

but it certainly uses the symbol `'and`.

Another problem is that lots of things, like `and`, are special forms that are implemented with macros.  You need to know what all of the macros in your program expand into to figure out even what variables are used in your program.

To make this work, you need to restrict the set of programs that you accept as input.  The best choice is to restrict it to "fully expanded" programs.  In other words, you want to make sure that there aren't any uses of macros left in the input to your `free-variables` function.

To do this, you can use the `expand` function provided by many Scheme systems.  Unfortunately, from the [online documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/mit-scheme/documentation/mit-scheme-ref/index.html#Top), it doesn't look like MIT Scheme provides this function.  If you're able to use a different system, [Racket](http://racket-lang.org/) provides the [`expand`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/Expanding_Top-Level_Forms.html#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._expand%29%29) function as well as [`local-expand`](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/stxtrans.html?q=local-expand#%28def._%28%28quote._~23~25kernel%29._local-expand%29%29) which works correctly inside macros.

Racket actually also provides an implementation of the [`free-variables` function](http://docs.racket-lang.org/syntax/syntax-helpers.html#%28mod-path._syntax/free-vars%29) that you ask for, which, as I described, requires fully expanded programs as input (such as the output of `expand` or `local-expand`).  You can see the [source code](https://github.com/plt/racket/blob/master/collects/syntax/free-vars.rkt#L46) as well.

For a detailed discussion of the issues involved with full expansion of source code, see [this upcoming paper](http://www.cs.utah.edu/plt/expmodel-6/) by Flatt, Culpepper, Darais and Findler.

Comment: Maybe not for arbitrarily large programs, but for simple lambda's at the top level environmet, I believe I have found the basis for a working solution.

Comment: Your solution doesn't work for any functions with binders (like `let` or `lambda`) inside them.

Comment: It wasn't `let` or `lambda` that was breaking it.. it was that I didn't safeguard against calling `environment-reference-type` with something other than a symbol.

Comment: You are correct though that it will not see the bindings in a let as having any value...